# Why I cannot create a class object inside a function?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I have my main code that contains several functions and I tested it and it works perfectly fine. I then create a class for `tkinter` window, and test it separately and it also works fine. When I incorporate the both of them together, by creating a class object inside a function, I get this error message:

`"TclError: can't invoke "frame" command: application has been destroyed"`

```
import tkinter

class InputFromForm():
    def __init__(self, root, values):
        self.field = []
        self.fieldStrings = values
        self.temp = self.makeform(self.fieldStrings)

    def makeform(self, fields):
        entries = []
        for i in fields:
            row = tkinter.Frame(root)
            lab = tkinter.Label(row, width=15, text=i, anchor='w')
            ent = tkinter.Entry(row)
            ent.insert(tkinter.END, fields[i])
            ent.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event, e=ent: e.selection_range(0, tkinter.END))
            row.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.X, padx=5, pady=10)
            lab.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
            ent.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, expand=tkinter.YES, fill=tkinter.X)
            entries.append((i, ent))

        return entries


    def fetch(self, entries):
        for entry in entries:
            string = entry[0]
            text  = entry[1].get()
            self.field.append(text)
        return self.field

    def close(self, root):
        root.destroy()


def extractData(dOfValues):
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title('Test')
    userInput = InputFromForm(root, dOfValues)
    root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=userInput.temp: userInput.fetch(e)))
    b1 = tkinter.Button(root, text='OK',command=(lambda e=userInput.temp: [userInput.fetch(e), userInput.close(root)]))
    b1.config(width=25)
    b1.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, padx=5, pady=20)


    root.mainloop()



if __name__ == '__main__':


    dOfValues = {'Customer No.': '',
            'PO #':'020202',
            'Order Date': '2/3/2012',
            'Zip to code':'92182'}

    #root = tkinter.Tk()
    #root.title('Test')

    #userInput = InputFromForm(root, dOfValues)

    #root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=userInput.temp: userInput.fetch(e)))
    #b1 = tkinter.Button(root, text='OK',command=(lambda e=userInput.temp: [userInput.fetch(e), userInput.close(root)]))
    #b1.config(width=25)
    #b1.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, padx=5, pady=20)


    #root.mainloop()
    extractData(dOfValues)  # Adding this, creates the error. If I put the code 
                            # from this function into main, it works.
```

Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: It looks like you have a coding error. You never actually save root in your class. You need to do `self.root = root`. And then `row = tkinter.Frame(self.root)`. It should really just give you a NameError, but maybe Tkinter has some error catching thats obfuscating the error.

Comment: The error is fairly self-explanatory. At one point you had a root window, it got destroyed, and now you are trying to create a frame in a window that no longer exists.

Comment: @Greg I added what you recommended, and I believe my `close()` method should just be: `self.root.destroy()`. I got another error: `"AttributeError: 'InputFromForm' object has no attribute 'root'"`.

Comment: @BryanOakley How did the root window got destroyed? I never destroyed it tho

Comment: What do you think `root.destroy()` in line 23 does?

Comment: Anyway yor code raises `NameError`, not `TclError`.

Comment: @Goyo Yes that destroys the windows. But if I never call it then how do I destroyed it?

Comment: Well you never call it because the code raises `NameError` before you have the chance so the question is moot. If you show the code that actually raises `TclError` maybe I or someone else will be able to answer.

Comment: @Goyo How should I go about asking for help? Do I need to make a new post showing the new error?

Comment: I don't know, I can't tell you what to ask. But whatever you do make sure that the code reproduces the problem. If you ask about a `TclError` and you show code that raises `NameError` the question does not make much sense. You can edit this question to make the code match the problem description or ask a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@paul "Printing and returning are completely unrelated"

are you sure? try this code.I think you can change it to retrieve what

you want, the values on your fields, if I've understand what you want.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class InputFromForm(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, root, values):
        self.field = []
        self.entries = []
        self.fieldStrings = values
        self.temp = self.makeform(self.fieldStrings)

    def makeform(self, fields):

        entries = []

        for i in fields:
            row = tk.Frame()
            lab = tk.Label(row, width=15, text=i, anchor='w')
            ent = tk.Entry(row)
            ent.insert(tk.END, fields[i])
            ent.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event, e=ent: e.selection_range(0, tk.END))
            row.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=10)
            lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.X)
            entries.append((i, ent))

        return entries 


    def fetch(self, entries):
        for entry in entries:
            string = entry[0]
            text  = entry[1].get()
            self.field.append(text)
        return self.field

    def close(self, root):

        msg = "Do you want to quit?\nI've this data for you\n {0}".format(self.field)

        if messagebox.askokcancel("Simple App", msg):
            root.destroy()



def extractData(dOfValues):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Test')
    userInput = InputFromForm(root, dOfValues)
    root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=userInput.temp: userInput.fetch(e)))
    b1 = tk.Button(root, text='OK',command=(lambda e=userInput.temp: [userInput.fetch(e), userInput.close(root)]))
    b1.config(width=25)
    b1.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, padx=5, pady=20)


    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':


    dOfValues = {'Customer No.': '',
            'PO #':'020202',
            'Order Date': '2/3/2012',
            'Zip to code':'92182'}

    #root = tk.Tk()
    #root.title('Test')

    #userInput = InputFromForm(root, dOfValues)

    #root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=userInput.temp: userInput.fetch(e)))
    #b1 = tk.Button(root, text='OK',command=(lambda e=userInput.temp: [userInput.fetch(e), userInput.close(root)]))
    #b1.config(width=25)
    #b1.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, padx=5, pady=20)


    #root.mainloop()
    extractData(dOfValues)  # Adding this, creates the error. If I put the code 
                            # from this function into main, it works.
```

Comment: Yes, I was gonna comment on your previous post, that it works, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what the problem is, however I've do some change

on your script. First I import tkinter as tk then I've inherit  your

class from Tk, see below.

```
import tkinter as tk

class InputFromForm(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, root, values):
        self.field = []
        self.fieldStrings = values
        self.temp = self.makeform(self.fieldStrings)

    def makeform(self, fields):
        entries = []
        for i in fields:
            row = tk.Frame()
            lab = tk.Label(row, width=15, text=i, anchor='w')
            ent = tk.Entry(row)
            ent.insert(tk.END, fields[i])
            ent.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event, e=ent: e.selection_range(0, tk.END))
            row.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=10)
            lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.X)
            entries.append((i, ent))

        return entries


    def fetch(self, entries):
        for entry in entries:
            string = entry[0]
            text  = entry[1].get()
            self.field.append(text)
        return self.field

    def close(self, root):
        root.destroy()


def extractData(dOfValues):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Test')
    userInput = InputFromForm(root, dOfValues)
    root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=userInput.temp: userInput.fetch(e)))
    b1 = tk.Button(root, text='OK',command=(lambda e=userInput.temp: [userInput.fetch(e), userInput.close(root)]))
    b1.config(width=25)
    b1.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, padx=5, pady=20)


    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':


    dOfValues = {'Customer No.': '',
            'PO #':'020202',
            'Order Date': '2/3/2012',
            'Zip to code':'92182'}

    #root = tk.Tk()
    #root.title('Test')

    #userInput = InputFromForm(root, dOfValues)

    #root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=userInput.temp: userInput.fetch(e)))
    #b1 = tk.Button(root, text='OK',command=(lambda e=userInput.temp: [userInput.fetch(e), userInput.close(root)]))
    #b1.config(width=25)
    #b1.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, padx=5, pady=20)


    #root.mainloop()
    extractData(dOfValues)  # Adding this, creates the error. If I put the code 
                            # from this function into main, it works.
```

I got this

[image]

Comment: @paul Why do you expect it to return anything different than `None`?

Comment: @Goyo Because I am returning the user input from the input field boxes, when I call fetch() method

Comment: @paul I mean, that's true, but why do you expect `extractData` to know or care about it?

Comment: @Goyo Sorry I can't follow, do you mean because I do not return anything thus I receive None? What I mean is, even if you `print(userInput.field)` just before root.mainloop(), you get an empty list. The code that I originally had, returns what is in the input fields.

Comment: the problem is that when you call fetch you call the close function. Try to add in close function something like  for i in self.field: print(i) before destroy.

Comment: @paul Now it is me who can't follow you. Printing and returning are completely unrelated.